# Heroku not recognizing requirements.txt file

Tags: python, heroku

My directory structure is

- Procfile
- script.py
- index.js
- package.json
- requirements.txt

and I am trying to run script.py as a scheduled cronjob.  The contents of my requirements.txt file are:

```
requests==2.23.0
pymongo==3.10.1
```

contents of Procfile:

```
web: node index.js
clock: python script.py
```

Yet my logs continually say:

```
2020-04-26T20:42:22.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user ****@gmail.com
2020-04-26T20:42:34.114621+00:00 heroku[clock.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-04-26T20:42:34.149809+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2020-04-26T20:42:34.153850+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2020-04-26T20:42:33.681917+00:00 app[api]: Deploy #### by user ****@gmail.com
2020-04-26T20:42:33.681917+00:00 app[api]: Release v11 created by user ****@gmail.com
2020-04-26T20:42:33.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-04-26T20:42:36.711949+00:00 heroku[clock.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-04-26T20:42:37.665706+00:00 app[web.1]: Server Running
2020-04-26T20:42:38.096571+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-04-26T20:42:38.187393+00:00 heroku[clock.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2020-04-26T20:42:38.134156+00:00 app[clock.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-04-26T20:42:38.134180+00:00 app[clock.1]: File "script.py", line 1, in <module>
2020-04-26T20:42:38.134187+00:00 app[clock.1]: import requests
2020-04-26T20:42:38.134187+00:00 app[clock.1]: ImportError: No module named requests
```

my understanding, based on the documentation, is that pushing requirements.txt should cause Heroku to automatically install my dependencies.  This is not happening.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gotta update the buildpack to use Python in addition to Node.

Comment: Your project is already using the Python buildpack else you wouldn't be able to run the python interpreter. The issue is something else or rather was if you already resolved your issue in some other way.